# Asynchronous JS issue -- Variable scoping or other mistake?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a listener on a `select` element's `change` event: on change, a file is fetched and a complicated SVG is calculated and loaded to the DOM (read: a fair number of CPU cycles required). Issue is if you change the `select` very quickly (via coded keyboard shortcuts), multiple things are loaded to the SVG container -- I only want one loaded at a time. To try to remedy this, I've done this (semi-pseudo):

```
select.on("change", function() { queue(this.val); });

var queuedFile, state = "ready";
function queue(file) {
    queuedFile = file;
    // NB: in real code, queuedFile is a property and the getter empties the queue
    if (state === "ready") { loadFile(queuedFile); }
}

function loadFile(file) {
    state = "busy";

    ajaxGet(file, function(result) {

        // lots of statements, iterators, calls to other fns

        state = "ready";
        // NB: again in real code the getter empties the queue
        var qf = queuedFile;
        if (qf) { clearSVG(); loadFile(qf); }

    }); // end ajaxGet
}
```

That is to say: on `select` change, queue the new file and if the file loader is not busy loading another file, load it, else do nothing. When the file loader is done, if there's a queued file, clear the SVG and load the queued file. Seems like this should only allow one file in the SVG container at once.

In practice, `state` is never `"busy"` when it's checked in `queue()`, so I'm still getting multiple files loaded to the SVG. A `console.log(state)` right after `state = "busy"` shows `"busy"` though. What am I missing here? I don't think it's an issue with the scope of `queuedFile`.

---

For completeness, my queue property is this:

```
// given: all of this code is enclosed in a function that returns an object "viewer".
// (only one instance of the "viewer" is created)

Object.defineProperty(viewer, "queuedFile", {
    get: function () {
        console.log("dequeuing", this.filequeue);
        var buffer = this.filequeue;
        this.filequeue = null;
        return buffer;
    },
    set: function (newval) {
        console.log("queuing", newval);
        this.filequeue = newval;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you just disable the <select> element when it is changed, and then re-enable it when the SVG operations are complete?

Comment: @ianpgall that'd work, but would be devastating to the UI.

Comment: What about it makes it devastating? Why queue up the select element changes, possibly creating tens of SVG operations that tie up the browser. You can still restore focus after it completes. You could also use a modal that shows "loading" that "disables" the whole page.

Comment: @ianpgall, The "queue" is a single slot, not an array. I want the user to be able to tap a key and say, get from option 1 to option 10 (by way of options 2 through 9 in the select elem), and only have option 1 load and then option 10 load in the SVG. I don't intend to load and unload everything from option 2 through option 10.

Comment: I see I see, sorry for the misunderstanding. Does this jsfiddle help? http://jsfiddle.net/2FNsh/1/

Comment: @ianpgall no worries, I wasn't the clearest. I couldn't quite get your jsfiddle to work, but I made [this fork](http://jsfiddle.net/FkMHw/1/) of it that does the deed. Will be back shortly after I test this in the larger code. Feel free to post your jsfiddle and/or my fork of it as an answer. Thanks much!

Comment: @ianpgall Your method works -- if you make it an answer I'll accept it. thanks

Comment: Glad I could help you at least figure out your problem!

Comment: I don't think you really should call it "queue", when it actually is only a single (or double?) slot. At the problem: I'd just abort any ongoing load processes when a change is triggered. Also, the SVG processsing seems to be synchronous, not sure whether that is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, this seems to help you!

http://jsfiddle.net/2FNsh/1/

And your fork that ultimately helped:

http://jsfiddle.net/FkMHw/1/